# How to store payload and append it to another payload later?

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration in my project. I have the following payload.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PQ>
   <PQContact>
      <hostAddress>10.193.244.136</hostAddress>
   </PQContact>
   <workflowStatusComment>
      <comment>I am here</comment>
   </workflowStatusComment>
</PQ>
```

I want to extract the tag `<workflowStatusComment>` i.e `workflowStatusComment <comment>I am here</comment></workflowStatusComment>` and save it for future purpose. I don't want to use any java code to use the saved tag info in the future. I want to add the saved info to another payload at the end of the execution.I know about header enrichers, but I don't know how to use the saved header enriched values without using java. I have to only use Spring Integration components to manipulate the payload.

The second payload to which I am going to append the saved tag info is here:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PQ>
   <PQContact>
      <hostAddress>10.193.244.136</hostAddress>
      <name>Ashok</name>
      <userId>007</userId>
   </PQContact>
 </PQ>
```

After appending the saved tag info to the above payload, my final payload should look like the initial payload with some extra information. Something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PQ>
   <PQContact>
      <hostAddress>10.193.244.136</hostAddress>
      <name>Ashok</name>
      <userId>007</userId>
   </PQContact>
   <workflowStatusComment>
      <comment>I am here</comment>
  </workflowStatusComment>
</PQ>
```

is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract that info from the XML using `<int-xml:xpath-transformer>` or `#xpath()` SpEL-function.

But you have to share with us what is your "another payload" and how you would like to add this extracted.

Maybe it even better to have some solution with Java and than we consider here how to convert it into Spring Integration XML DSL or similar.

Please, revise your question to make it more clearer.

**UPDATE**

To insert one XML into another you have to fight a bit `javax.xml` API.

The code might be something like this:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

Document target = builder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(targetXML));
Element source = builder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(sourceXML)).getDocumentElement();


target.appendChild(source);
```

**UPDATE 2**

> But I don't want to use any java code.

Well, if your target XML can represent as a template string you can use standard `replaceFirst()` in the `<transformer>` with `expression`:

String targetXml = "";

```
<transformer expression="'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PQ>
   <PQContact>
      <hostAddress>10.193.244.136</hostAddress>
      <name>Ashok</name>
      <userId>007</userId>
   </PQContact>
   $workflowStatusCommentToken$
</PQ>'.replaceFirst('\\$workflowStatusCommentToken\\$', headers.originalXml)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have edited the question. Please take a look now.

Comment: I have edited the question. Could you please provide the solution if exists?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Hmm...That's okay... But I don't want to use any java code. Is there any way to update the payload info with the saved header information using the Spring Integration components?